# Why does everyone still use the name "Jay Garrick"?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In Season Two of Flash, as we learn more about Jay Garrick, we learn that

> the character calling himself Jay is really Hunter Zoloman, aka Zoom, and that he stole Jay Garrick's name.

With that in mind, why is everyone continuing to use the name "Jay Garrick" when talking about him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In-universe, when they learn that "Jay Garrick" is actually Hunter Zolomon, a psychopath from Earth 2, they don't know about the existence of a real Jay Garrick and think that name is just a random stage name for his Earth-2 Flash persona, and not the name of a real person (the Earth-3's Flash). For them, Jay Garrick=Hunter Zolomon=Zoom.

Since they are used to call him that way, they have no reason to change. The real name of the famous actor Michael Caine is Maurice Micklewhite Jr..  Knowing this, will you change the way you call him?

Out-of-universe, it is for convenience for the audience.

Comment: Right - same reason they keep calling Eobard "[The other] Dr Wells" long after they discover he's no such thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I wanted to add this to my answer, but was not sure of it.

Comment: Maurice Micklewhite Jr?! Definitely calling him that from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Okay major spoilers:

> There were lots of twists here; Zoom was impersonating Jay Garrick, AKA the man in the iron mask. So when Barry and company finally liberated the real Jay Garrick (played by John W Shipp). Jay eventually went back to Earth-3 where he is the Flash.
>
> The real Jay Garrick becomes a mentor to Barry in the next season.
>
> And when Zoom killed the fake Jay Garrick; that was actually Zoom killing one of his own time remnants!
>
> UPDATE: So to answer your question, they call him Jay because that's what they have known him as the longest.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'm just curious on why they use the older name after the gang all knows of the real name.

Comment: @CBredlow: Oh, the gang only knows Hunter as Jay Garrick that's why

Comment: wells straight up says it in front of everyone, and Barry knows, and they keep calling him Jay

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually answer anything relating to the question being asked.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: See my comment above; I added my comment into my answer. And honestly I didn't fully understand what the OP was asking...